# Python virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper workon xxx

Tags: python, batch-file, virtualenv

Working a project with a development track that requires a 'workon xxx' to build the development track and a 'deactivate' to go back to the standard python to build the stable track. Using the Windows command line switching between python environment works great. However, when using 'workon xxx' from a batch script the it it doesn't return to execute the next line. It drops to the command line. I have tried 'call workon xxx' and the result is the same.

How can 'workon xxx' be called from a batch script and return to execute the next line?

Answer (score 3):

`call` should work just fine:

```
c:\srv\tmp> cat workoncall.bat
@echo off

call workon dev
call cdsitepackages
echo %CD%

call workon pydeps
call cdsitepackages
echo %CD%

(pydeps) c:\srv\tmp> workoncall.bat
c:\srv\venv\dev\Lib\site-packages
C:\srv\venv\pydeps\Lib\site-packages
```